# Error installing Sublime text command line functionality

Tags: terminal, installation, sublimetext

I'm trying to install a symbolic link to Sublime Text (i.e. being able to type "subl Foo.java" into the terminal and launching Sublime). I'm using the following: ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/sublime (which is provided at http://olivierlacan.com/posts/launch-sublime-text-3-from-the-command-line/). However, I'm getting the following error:

```
ln: /usr/local/bin/sublime: File exists
```

I've tried editing my path file but nothing seems to be working. Has anyone had a similar problem and have a fix?

Comment: This error typically occurs when there is already a file of that name in target directory. In your case you probably already have sublime in /usr/local/bin. You can verify that using `ls -l /usr/local/bin/sublime`

Comment: What can I do to fix this? I looked in the directory and it's empty.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your symlink is still existing, so there is no need to create it twice. Maybe you put the line

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/sublime
```

into your `.bash_profile`? if your `/usr/local/bin/sublime` file exists there is no need for that.